# At the earlier I was using JavaWebStart application to launch jnlp but now it is failing in some machines after cloudbees update, Any solution?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

At the earlier JavaWebStart application to launch jnlp application but now it is failing after cloudbees update, Now I'm connecting it with agent.jar but it is disconnected frequently and I need solution for this

Comment: You need to [provide more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Old version, new version, OSs, error msg, what do you see in the logs, etc.

Comment: latest release - 2.319.1.5, previous release - 2.303.3.3

Comment: Message in Logs? Jdk change?

Comment: I have captured the log and mentioned the error below:                                    
SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:864)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:804)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:540)

Comment: OpenJDK version 1.8.0_41

Comment: @Scratte,@lan W, Please let me know if you have any solution about this issue

Comment: You should add any relevant information to your Question. It should be so that all comments can be deleted with no information lost. Can you also add exactly the minimal thing someone needs to do to get exactly the same error are you're getting?

Comment: Read this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309316/the-server-rejected-the-connection-none-of-the-protocols-were-accepted)>