# Jenkins Windows Slave setup using Winsw not working

Tags: jenkins, winsw

Using this info https://hayato-iriumi.net/2019/05/23/how-to-install-jenkins-slave-as-windows-service/ we are setting up the Jenkins Slave on Windows server. Jenkins agent start from command line. but when we start from Windows service, its giving below error message? How to resolve this error message?

```
Service cannot be started. System.IO.InvalidDataException: Attribute <className> is missing in configuration XML
   at winsw.Util.XmlHelper.SingleAttribute[TAttributeType](XmlElement node, String attributeName)
   at winsw.Extensions.WinSWExtensionDescriptor.FromXml(XmlElement node)
   at winsw.Extensions.WinSWExtensionManager.LoadExtension(String id)
   at winsw.Extensions.WinSWExtensionManager.LoadExtensions()
   at winsw.WrapperService.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

**xml file we have**

```
<service>
  <id>JenkinsSlave</id>
  <name>Jenkins agent</name>
  <description>This service runs an agent for Jenkins automation server.</description>
  <executable>c:\java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -jar "c:\jenkins\slave.jar" -jnlpUrl https://jenkinsmaster/jenkins/computer/slave01/slave-agent.jnlp -secret a4b5b4ddfd34a016cd3a8eb94cbe8f908613e33a66db5fa6f5f43a080aea3116 -workDir=c:\jenkins</arguments>
  <workingdirectory>c:\jenkins</workingdirectory>
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>
  <onfailure action="restart">
    <download from="https://jenkinsmaster/jenkins/jnlpJars/slave.jar" to="c:\jenkins\slave.jar"> 
        <extensions>
            <extension enabled="false" classname="winsw.Plugins.RunawayProcessKiller.RunawayProcessKillerExtension" id="killOnStartup">
                <pidfile>c:\jenkins\jenkins_agent.pid</pidfile>
                <stoptimeout>5000</stoptimeout>
                <stopparentfirst>false</stopparentfirst>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </download>
  </onfailure>
</service>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add your "jenkins-slave.xml".

Comment: @zett42 added xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in the sample "Jenkins-Slave.xml" that is presented at the linked web page (which yours is apparently based on). It has all elements and attributes named in lowercase, but actually some of them should be mixed case (as can be seen by the error message that it doesn't find attribute `className`).

Try this one instead:

```xml
<service>
  <id>YourJenkinsSlaveServiceId</id>
  <name>Your Jenkins Slave Service Name</name>
  <description>This service runs an agent for Jenkins automation server.</description>
  <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\bin\java.exe</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -jar "%BASE%\slave.jar" -jnlpUrl http://YourJenkinsServer:8080/computer/YourNodeName/slave-agent.jnlp -secret YourSecretStringConsistingOfHexadecimalCharacters -workDir=C:\YourNodeWorkDir</arguments>
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>
  <onfailure action="restart" />
  <download from="http://YourJenkinsServer:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar" to="%BASE%\slave.jar"/>
 <extensions>
    <extension enabled="true" className="winsw.Plugins.RunawayProcessKiller.RunawayProcessKillerExtension" id="killOnStartup">
      <pidfile>%BASE%\jenkins_agent.pid</pidfile>
      <stopTimeout>5000</stopTimeout>
      <stopParentFirst>false</stopParentFirst>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</service>
```

This is from a more detailed explanation of how to install an agent as a Windows service which I have given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60399024/7571258).

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked. one question in your xml file. Where do define `%BASE%` environment variable?

Comment: @sfgroups This is not a real env var. It is just a placeholder for the base directory where the XML file is located.

Comment: Thanks, with this we can use `openjdk` to install Jenkisn.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate jenkins.xml file within executable directory or any parents
   at winsw.ServiceDescriptor..ctor()
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
```

**Solution:**

Save your jenkins-agent file in XML format, not just `jenkins-agent.xml`. You can use Notepad++ to save the XML type. Similarly, remove `.exe` at the end of `jenkins-agent.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

The `className`, `stopTimeout` and `stopParentFirst` should not be in lower case.