# The orange botton to lunch slave-agent.jnlp is not showing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I tried to download the `slave-agent.jnlp` file but I can't even find the orange button to download the file. I am only seeing this link below.

> Java Web Start is not available for the JVM version running Jenkins

you can also find an attached snapshot of the issue I'm facing.

[image]

Comment: The solution is to configure the slave manually, basically by letting it execute the command-line as shown in your screenshot. On Windows you could also install the slave as a service (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60399024/7571258)).

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and give a feedback

Comment: Thank you so much, the mistake I made was not following the jenkins installation process sequentially. Note Java is a perquisite for  jenkins. Therefore when setting up jenkins environment we need to  install JDK and set environment variables ( you can do this by watching this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_nF2RnyfDU"). Remember you need to do this before installing and starting jenkins. After you complete the java process in the youtube video then install jenkins .