# How to keep a windows node always connected to jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, jnlp

I have a jenkins instance installed on a oracle linux box, and I have attached a windows node to that using the method `"Launch agent by connecting to the controller"`
This windows is also a remote server which I access from Remote Desktop Connection Manager(RDC).
The issue is to connect the node to jenkins, every time I need to login to the windows server from RDC and execute the agent.jar file with a following like command

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://serverIP:8000/jenkins/manage/computer/my-project/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret @secret-file -workDir "H:\Jenkins_slave"
```

if I close the cmd window or close the RDC session, this node get disconnected from jenkins. How I can keep this node always connected even if my session on RDC expires/close the cmd window ??

Comment: [Install the agent as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60399024/7571258) (using the jenkins service wrapper). If this doesn't work, you could try to run it via scheduled task.

Comment: If you're on windows you could download the jnlp file on to your server and run it as you would run an ordinary exe. This should configure everything for you automatically.