# Port not reachable error while launching agent in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins launch method as "launch agent by connecting to the master". While clicking launch button , getting error message as

provided port:@@@@ is not reachable
atorg.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:302)
at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:523)
at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:474)

Can anyone help on this

Agent is showing as offline . I have tried different launch method as "launch agent via execution of command on the master" with command "java -jar C:\jenkins\agent.jar". this is throwing error as
`your text`java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
`your text`at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
`your text`at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
`your text`at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
`your text`at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
`your text`at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
`your text`at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$2.flush(BinarySafeStream.java:305)
`your text`at `your text`java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1823)
`your text`at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:719)
`your text`at hudson.remoting.Capability$1.close(Capability.java:132)
`your text`at hudson.remoting.Capability.writePreamble(Capability.java:144)

Comment: Are you trying to get a Jenkins agent node connected to the master node?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to connect   with new launch method as "by connecting to the master " as " let jenkins control this window slave as window service " is not working(machine became offline) after the security patch.

Comment: Is there a hard requirement on the way you use to connect to the node? Or is it fine if you use some other method such as the Jenkins service wrapper. Here is a good answer on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60399024/3730626