# Jenkins - Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed

Tags: windows, jenkins, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

Previously I had an issue connecting a windows agent to Jenkins.
Then ["This question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372214/jnlp-connections-are-deprecated-in-jenkins-what-is-the-new-recommended-way-conne/60399024#60399024) I referred and now I have connected a windows agent to Jenkins using a service wrapper.

But now the issue is, for doing the automation test "microsoft edge" browser should be launched while executing the pipeline.
Now I am getting this error.

```
Microsoft Edge WebDriver was started successfully.
[ERROR] Tests run: 15, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 14, Time elapsed: 2.794 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] beforeMethod(abc.test.Route)  Time elapsed: 1.605 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'xxxxxx', ip: 'xxxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF66B3F4AD2+67490]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B38B242+782402]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B12C646]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B15A5A1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B155941]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B195A35]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B18DD23]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B162794]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B1619B0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B162F04]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF66B5B90D3+1301571]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF66B1EB951]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B2D46C1+33985]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B2CCAF5+2293]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF66B5B7E33+1296803]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B392589+811913]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B38EF04+797956]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B38EFFC+798204]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF66B3850B1+757425]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF92F4784D4+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF9306D1791+33]

    at abc.test.Route.beforeMethod(Route.java:30)
```

when I execute directly on the server without using jenkins it executes perfectly. I think the reason is jenkins using a service account and that doesn't allow to launch ms edge. Any solution for this ?

Thanks is advance..!